# How to use DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for non auto increment key(reg_id) ?  I'll insert that values from another table.So i want to insert a new raw if there aren't a sending reg_id if there is i want to update values in other columns ...

**My SQL create table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  student_subjects(

    reg_id INT(4),
    primary_maths VARCHAR(100),
    .....................etc
```

**MY SQL Insert**

```
           INSERT INTO student_subjects(reg_id,primary_maths ,.................
    ........etc) VALUES(?,?,...............etc) ON DUPLICATE 
KEY UPDATE reg_id=VALUES(reg_id);
```

Comment: Do you have only primary key or also unique index on other fields? I think that can be the clue why it inserts instead of updating.

Comment: reg_id INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: I get this id and send to the  student_subjects table

Comment: That's strange. Can you add a couple of examples to question? Existing row and inserted data.

Answer (score 1):

But it's written in [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Something like `... on duplicate key update reg_id = reg_id + 1` instead of `values(reg_id)`

or `... on duplicate key update primary_maths = 42, lalala = 'hohoho'`

Comment: I just now checked it it will create a another raw

Comment: That's strange. Are you sure that you don't change primary key in `on duplicate key update...`?

Comment: And maybe I was mistaken about `values()`. Maybe in your case you need to use them to avoid inserting of new row.